# Load Product Image from Url

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, external-images

We have created the product programmatically and we want to use the image from external link instead of default magento way but we are unable to load the images from external link in magento2.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/